# execute commands on remote server using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I have a deployment script located on a build server. Each time I need to generate the build I need to login to the server using `ssh` and then trigger the deployment script. 
I managed to generate the public/private keys so that I need not enter the password to login to the build server. But still I need to login and run the deployment script.
Is there a way where to automate the login, executing the deployment script on the build server and then exit from in one local script. How to achieve this

Comment: Well, you can certainly execute a call to `ssh` in a local script and hand over code or a remote file to be executed remotely. That is well documented and you can find endless examples for that on the internet.

Comment: Did some1 answer your question, or do you want to automate the login too ? If so what are those criteria (like time or event)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a pipe (assuming you are using a *nix OS):

```
echo "your --command --here" | ssh user@host
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's just

```
ssh buildserver /path/to/build.sh
```

You may need to tweak the options though.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `ssh <HOST> <COMMAND>` in a single line.  If you can already
log in using keys you won't have to type a password. Example:

```
$ ssh localhost 'echo hi'
hi
```

This `<COMMAND>` is run *synchronously*.  That means that `ssh` won't
finish until `<COMMAND>` run on the remote server has finished. See yourself:

```
$ ssh localhost 'sleep 10'
```

This command will wait for 10 seconds and you won't be able to type new commands until it's finished.

Comment: Then it is synchronous right.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand - is it a question?

Comment: @Pradeep everything without a `&` at the end is synchronous.

Comment: You have mentioned it is asynchronous in your answer. I think it is synchronous since you will not be able to run any commands till the command on the remote server is finished.

Comment: That's correct. Just add `&` after the `COMMAND` to make it *asynchronous*

Comment: There are two ways in which this can be made asynchronous. The remote command can be started in the background, allowing `ssh` to exit once it is started, or `ssh` itself can be run in the background on the local machine.

Comment: That's right. And I think that putting `&` after the whole command would make things slightly faster because the wrapper that calls `ssh` could immediately move on to the next line w/o even waiting for connection to be established. It just depends on what OP wants to do.